Measuring brushed DC motor inductance
I am trying to measure the inductance of a brushed DC motor for which I have a specification sheet from the manufacturer.  The spec sheet states an inductance of 1.8 mH (and a resistance of 0.05 Ohms).  However, when I measured the inductance using two different LCR meters I obtained a reading of approximately 700 µH on both of them.  The measurement varied a little with measurement frequency, decreasing to approximately 600 µH at higher test frequencies.
Is this large of a discrepancy to be expected, or is there perhaps an issue with the motor and/or spec sheet?

Seems legit....

Since we know neither the motor model, nor the LCR meter models, nor do we have any pictures or know the frequency at which you tested, it's hard to tell.
However, since it is a brushed motor which typically has at least three coils connected to the commutator at the same time, they will be in parallel or series/parallel via the commutator and will thus give you a lower value, while the manufacturer may have specified the coils separately before connecting them together via the commutator.
The only way to check this is to separate one side of one coil and then measure it, but then you might damage the commutator.
Again, you haven't given us a model or a picture of the inside of your motor, so a more definitive answer can't be given.

The meter was a fairly generic Amazon LCR meter in the $150 range.  I don't think the meter is the issue since another meter at my workplace gave very close readings.

The motor is made by Leeson.  I also measured a second Leeson motor of the same model, and the inductance values were very close.
It would not be typical for a manufacturer to specify the inductance of the individual coils, correct?  I assume that a typical motor specification sheet would give inductance and resistance values as measured at the terminals.
I found a Maxon motor, and the inductance was very close to that of the spec sheet.  I'm thinking that the Leeson spec sheet was incorrect.

@molecularlionel Two different models of LCR meters giving about the same value usually means they're correct. I can't tell you for sure whether the motor rating is for a single coil or the terminals. Try measuring at the terminals after pushing the rotor to spin in one direction by a couple degrees! If the brush connects across two contacts on the commutator, it practically shorts out one of the coils, giving you the other two in parallel, if it has three coils. "Made by Leeson" doesn't tell me details about your specific model. Can you provide link to DATASHEET?

Rotating the commutator has no significant effect.  The datasheet can be found here: https://ids.regalrexnord.com/CnxDocRequest/PublishedPDF/2020/documents/CAD%20Drawing_108053.00_PERF_TC_A_8078704_329.pdf

@molecularlionel Thank you for the datasheet. If you have another motor, same model, and it measures close to 1.8 mH, then it's possible some insulation between turns has been burnt or damaged.  If the resistance is significantly less than 0.05 Ω or 50 mΩ, that's another indicator of shorted turns of wire.

As I mentioned above, a second motor of the same model had an inductance in a similar range (600-700 µH).  I now believe the spec sheet is simply incorrect.

@molecularlionel I apologize, I was very busy and forgot about that.  I can't give you an answer at this time. Your conclusion may be correct, the manufacturer may have changed something without reflecting that in the datasheet.
